# Position icon on right hand side of the div

Tags: css, angular

I'd like to position the delete icon in my div list on the right hand side.

I've tried the following, however it does not seem to be working:

```css
.example-list {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #f1f4f8;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.example-box {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f4f8;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-list">
  <div class="example-box">
    <i style="padding-right: 10px">=</i>
    <span>Test 1</span>
    <i style="float: right; padding-left: 10px">x</i>
  </div>
  <div class="example-box">
    <i class="feather-align-right" style="padding-right: 10px">=</i>
    <span>Test 2</span>
    <i style="float: right; padding-left: 10px">x</i>
  </div>
  <div class="example-box">
    <i class="feather-align-right" style="padding-right: 10px">=</i>
    <span>Test 3</span>
    <i style="float: right; padding-left: 10px">x</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Link to Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-sortable-1atiju?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

Comment: use position: absolute and right: 40px  as styling https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-sortable-d3c4pj?file=styles.css and I suggest u to not write style codes in html

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't work when the list is in a scrollable container (position absolute)

Comment: then you need to change parents display flex to block if you want to use float right @methuselah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:block` rather than `display:flex` for `example-box` class

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" style="display:block" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    <i class="feather-align-right" style="padding-right: 10px"></i>
    <span [innerText]="movie"></span>
    <i class="feather-delete" style="float: right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```